# Adding Paths (routes) dynamically in resteasy

Tags: java, rest, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

How to add routes dynamically in resteasy (or jax-rs implementation).Right now, I add the routes with @Path annotation.
**Example**

```
@Controller
@Path("/api")
public class Controller {
    @GET
    @Path("/route1")
    public String route1() {
        return "Welcome ";
    }
}
```

But, I need to add more routes at runtime based on some user input. My aim is create rest apis at runtime based on user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your path as a regular expression. Here is the [tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Using__Path_and__GET___POST__etc..html).

So it shall look like this:

```
@Controller
@Path("/api")
public class Controller {
    @GET
    @Path("/{subPath}")
    public String subPath() {
        return "Welcome ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand that we can use {subPath} and based on the value of the subPath, we can have different endPoint implementation.

But, my requirement something different. These subPaths or endPoint will be added at runtime or at application start time. Assume there is a config file, where you can add new endPoints (or paths).  Is there any way to achieve it in resteasy or other JAX-RS implementation ?

Comment: Maybe you need to have one method that will check input string and will call other methods depending on input?

Comment: Agreed. I understand that. But, it will be really messy to have conditions and redirecting based on it. It will be like writing a controller by yourself. Instead, I would prefer to add Paths dynamic. IS there a way to do it ?